# Is there go up line character? (Opposite of \n)

Tags: text-processing, awk, escape-characters

In `awk` is there a go up character? I found something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474391/is-there-go-up-line-character-opposite-of-n) but it doesn't work.

For below:

```
97
ARE
3
NL
1303
1
140
USA
```

If record is not numeric need to print it as below

```
97,ARE
3,NL
1303
1
140,USA
```

Comment: @don_crissti there is no sequential non-numeric records, for the question title, it is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's better to handle this programmatically rather than trying to move the cursor around:

```
awk '/^[[:digit:]]+$/ { if (length(prev) > 0) { print prev }; prev = $0 } !/^[[:digit:]]+$/ { print (length(prev) > 0 ? prev : "") "," $0; prev = ""} END { if (length(prev) > 0) { print prev } }'
```

will produce the output you're after. It memorises the previous line in `prev`, and depending on whether it encounters numeric content in the next line, prints it out on its own or with a comma and the current line.

Here the Awk part, formatted so it's easier to understand:

```
/^[[:digit:]]+$/ {
    if (length(prev) > 0) {
        print prev
    }
    prev = $0
}
!/^[[:digit:]]+$/ {
    print (length(prev) > 0 ? prev : "") "," $0
    prev = ""
}
END {
    if (length(prev) > 0) {
        print prev
    }
}
```

If you really to want to move a character up, check out [`tput`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tput.1.html) and [`terminfo` escape sequences](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/terminfo.5.html):

```
tput cuu1
```

will move the cursor up one line.